# php : Change forms Dynamically Respect to user input with out using a framework

Tags: php, forms, dynamic, dynamicform

I'm trying to create a form like : http://webhelpdesk.demo.solarwinds.com/helpdesk/WebObjects/Helpdesk.woa/wa/login?username=client&password=client&ui=client

The fields are changed according to the user's selection. The combinations are quite large. The form changes for almost all the selected values.

Is there a specific design pattern or some architectural guide line for creating such forms?

How can I implement such a form using PHP?

Comment: The ability to change the DOM relies on JavaScript and is best approached implementing AJAX calls to retrieve data for populating drop-downs, creating new input fields and selecting/deselecting radios and checkboxes. I've never seen a PHP-only way of doing this. If it does exist, I'm sure it's massive and clunky. What's your beef with frameworks? jQuery was specifically written to lighten the load on coders who are JS-heavy.

Comment: I'm also planning to Ajax to do this, but the point is to code this in a more maintainable manner. If a user select a value form the dropdown, new fields are added to the form and some fields are removed. If the user selects a value form another dropdown, the form changes again. (As in the link provided above) What would be the best practice to do this? 
Thank You

Comment: Plain and simple - jQuery and a database of form options.

Answer (score 0):

A pure PHP implementation would require 2 forms one to select the other but it would look a little something like this.

```
<?php
     $formTypes = array("HR Form"=>"forms/hrform.php",
                        "Accounting Form"=>"forms/accounting.php");
     $selectedForm = isset($_GET["form"])?$_GET["form"]:"HR Form"; // the else indicates the default 
?>
<form name='formSelector' method='get'>
    <select name='form'>
          <?php foreach($formTypes as $label=>$form): ?>
           <option value="<?= $label ?>"<?= $selectedForm == $label?" selected='selected':"" ?>><?= $label ?></option>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    <input type='submit' value='Select Form'/>
</form>
<?php include ($formTypes[$selectedForm]); ?>
```

for each of the forms you would have something like this...

=== forms/hrform.php ===

```
<?php
   if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
       // validate and process the form
       // on successful process display confirmation and return    
   }
   // show the form html
?>
```

Comment: If I use AJAX to fetch the appropriate form for the currently selected values, What is the best practice to keep the list of fields that should be used for the currently selected values of the form.

e.g: in the above link if I select "HR request" new fields gets added. How should I keep track of the list of fields that are relevant for "HR request". What is the best practice for it?
Should I use a JSON file?
Thank You

Comment: personally I include in each field a hidden input that told me which form it is when it is posted then use a switch statement on the processor to manage the specifics of each form (like what fields are expected what validation should be done etc). There is 1000 ways to skin that cat... pick the one that makes the most sense to you.